# trouble building trilininos using cmake

Tags: cmake, trilinos

I am trying to build trilinos in fedora25 guest (virtualbox). Followed procedure described here:

http://iltabiai.github.io/peridynamics/fedora/tips/2016/04/20/Peridigm141-Fedora23.html

I had to adapt the build script from above link so that it could find Netcdf and HDF5 on my system.

trilinos builds with these errors in CMakeError.log :

```
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test FINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISNAN failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_44df3/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx    -O2 -ansi -pedantic -ftrapv -Wall -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -DFINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISNAN   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:6:10: error: ‘isnan’ was not declared in this scope
   isnan(x);
          ^
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:6:10: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/cmath:662:5: note:   ‘std::isnan’
     isnan(_Tp __x)
     ^~~~~
CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/src.cxx.o' failed
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_44df3.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_44df3/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTC_44df3/fast] Error 2

Source file was:

#include <cmath>
int main()
{
  double x = 1.0;
  isnan(x);
  return 0;
}

Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test FINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISINF failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_4cb6e/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx    -O2 -ansi -pedantic -ftrapv -Wall -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -DFINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISINF   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:6:10: error: ‘isinf’ was not declared in this scope
   isinf(x);
          ^
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:6:10: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/cmath:635:5: note:   ‘std::isinf’
     isinf(_Tp __x)
     ^~~~~
CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/src.cxx.o' failed
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_4cb6e.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_4cb6e/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTC_4cb6e/fast] Error 2

Source file was:

#include <cmath>
int main()
{
  double x = 1.0;
  isinf(x);
  return 0;
}

Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_78ecb/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_78ecb
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc      -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_78ecb 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_78ecb.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_78ecb' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_78ecb] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_78ecb/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTC_78ecb/fast] Error 2

File /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_5fb6c/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_5fb6c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_5fb6c -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fb6c.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_5fb6c' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_5fb6c] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_5fb6c/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTC_5fb6c/fast] Error 2


Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test HAVE_TEUCHOS_LAPACKLARND failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_93b6d/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx    -O2 -ansi -pedantic -ftrapv -Wall -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -DHAVE_TEUCHOS_LAPACKLARND   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:12:38: error: narrowing conversion of ‘0.0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
   int seed[4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
                                      ^
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:12:38: error: narrowing conversion of ‘0.0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:12:38: error: narrowing conversion of ‘0.0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:12:38: error: narrowing conversion of ‘1.0e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/src.cxx.o' failed
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_93b6d.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_93b6d/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTC_93b6d/fast] Error 2

Return value: 1
Source file was:

#define F77_BLAS_MANGLE(name,NAME) name ## _

#define DLARND_F77   F77_BLAS_MANGLE(dlarnd,DLARND)

extern "C" { double DLARND_F77(const int* idist, int* seed); }

int main()
{

  const int idist = 1;
  int seed[4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

  double val = DLARND_F77(&idist, seed);

  return (val < 0.0 ? 1 : 0);

}

Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test HAVE_CXX_PRAGMA_WEAK failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_21bab/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx    -O2 -ansi -pedantic -ftrapv -Wall -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CXX_PRAGMA_WEAK   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:14:22: warning: the address of ‘void A::theFunction()’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
   if (A::theFunction != NULL) {
                      ^
Linking CXX executable cmTC_21bab
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx    -O2 -ansi -pedantic -ftrapv -Wall -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CXX_PRAGMA_WEAK    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_21bab 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/src.cxx.o: In function `main':
src.cxx:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `A::theFunction()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_21bab.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_21bab' failed
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_21bab] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/peri/packages/trilinos-12.10.1-Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_21bab/fast' failed
gmake: *** [cmTC_21bab/fast] Error 2

Source file was:

#include <iostream>

namespace A {
// theFunction never gets defined, because we
// don't link with a library that defines it.
// That's OK, because it's weak linkage.
#pragma weak theFunction
extern void theFunction ();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hi!  I am main." << std::endl;
  if (A::theFunction != NULL) {
    // Should never be called, since we don't link
    // with a library that defines A::theFunction.
    A::theFunction ();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**how can these errors be eliminated?**

Comment: Plese, show **configuration** log too (that is, what output of `cmake` itself). File `CMakeError.log` contains NOT a **project's build** errors: these are errors occured at **configuration** time, when different *compilation* **tests** are performed. While failing some of these tests seems suspicios, by themselves they do not prohibit building the project. Unless the project finds some of these fails in tests as fatal.

Comment: @Tsyvarev where can I can find this configuration log?

Comment: meawhile, CMakeOutput.log can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FQ1IVrf1FnN1dvZ2dRUHliSkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When run `cmake` for your project, you should get some output. Provide this output.

Comment: Try adding `-D FINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISNAN=OFF` and `-D FINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISINF=OFF` to your cmake command line.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this is what I saw on the screen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FQ1IVrf1FnME1RbVFVT0lVUVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Lines `Configuring done`, `-- Generating done`, `-- Build files have been written to:` mean that the configuration is completed and the project can be built.

Comment: @Tsyvarev now I am concerned about the failed tests: FINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISNAN
FINITE_VALUE_HAVE_GLOBAL_ISINF
HAVE_TEUCHOS_LAPACKLARND
HAVE_CXX_PRAGMA_WEAK by the way addition of to cmake command line -D Trilinos_ENABLE_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATION=ON made it possible for me to successfully complete make -j 4